# IPhone SDK - Leaking Memory with performSelectorInBackground

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

Maybe someone can help me with this strange thing:

If a user clicks on a button, a new UITableView is pushed to the navigation controller. This new view is doing some database querying which takes some time. Therefore I wanted to do the loading in background.

What works WITHOUT leaking memory (but freezes the screen until everything is done):

```
WorkController *tmp=[[WorkController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
self.workController=tmp;
[tmp release];

[self.workController loadList]; // Does the DB Query
[self.workController pushViewController:self.workController animated:YES];
```

Now I tried to do this:

```
    // Show Wait indicator
    ....

    WorkController *tmp=[[WorkController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.workController=tmp;
    [tmp release];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getController) withObject:nil];
}

-(void) getController {
    [self.workController loadList]; // Does the DB Query
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.workController animated:YES];
}
```

This also works but is leaking memory and I don't know why !
Can you help ?

By the way - is it possible for an App to get into AppStore with a small memory leak ? Or will this be checked first of all ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi,

leak is within the getController method.

Comment: Um, where? You don't release workController??

Answer (score 5):

No, small memory leaks will not (most likely) you application to be rejected from appstore.

In your example as you run your method in separate thread you should create and dispose `NSAutoreleasePool` object for that thread to handle autoreleased objects. Following changes to `getController` method should do the trick:

```
-(void) getController {
    NSAutoreleasedPool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasedPool alloc] init];

    [self.workController loadList]; // Does the DB Query
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.workController animated:YES];

    [pool release];
}
```

For more details see [Autorelease Pools](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047) section in memory management guide. Relevant quote from there:

> If you spawn a secondary thread, you
>   must create your own autorelease pool
>   as soon as the thread begins
>   executing; otherwise, you will leak
>   objects. (See [“Autorelease Pools and
>   Threads”](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-1041876) for details.)

Comment: First of all - thanks for your reply. But where is the NSAutorelease Pool used ? Isn't it just allocated and released ?

Comment: Thanks ! Using pool did the trick. It works now without leaking (and it IS possible to push a view to stack in background thread)

Comment: NSAutoreleasePool handles autoreleased objects and make sure that they will be actually released. Although you it looks like you just create and release it it does a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, you're calling `pushViewController:` from a background thread. This is bad.

You should only do things to the UI - like pushing view controllers and changing UI items - from the main thread. If you don't, things break.

See the Cocoa Fundamentals Guide section titled "Are the Cocoa Frameworks Thread Safe?": it says "All UIKit objects should be used on the main thread only."