# (iphone) show custom activity indicator?

Tags: iphone, imageview, uiactivityindicatorview

I've made a custom activity indicator (actually just an imageView)

When user clicks something and I expect it will take a bit long to process(alloc a UIViewController and push on to navigation stack),
I alloc the indicator and add it as subview of current view just before the lengthy process starts.

Strange thing is, indicator doesn't show up until the push (left-right) animation starts.

Is it because the lengthy job takes the system, and ui drawing for activity indicator is delayed?

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thank you

- Edit

Looks like I can do the "push" in background.. i'm trying it now
[IPhone SDK - Leaking Memory with performSelectorInBackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441856/iphone-sdk-leaking-memory-with-performselectorinbackground)

Answer (score 1):

Is your job synchrone or asynchrone ?

If it's the first case, then it can be the problem.

Check all the method like :

```
[ self performSelector:<#(SEL)aSelector#> ];
```

You can thread this to avoid your [potential] problem.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should process your lengthy tasks in the background. The UI won't update if you block the main thread.

So you have to refactor your app, the alloc and push of the viewController should happen within the blink of an eye, because you can't do this in the background.

But you can do the processing (downloading data I guess) in the background.

There is plenty information available about background processing. The way to go varies heavily on what you want to do exactly.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt thanks, actually, alloc/push itself is fast, just it seems when the viewController is pushed, loadingView for the viewController is slow. Does it make my problem any easier to solve?

Comment: of course everything that happens in methods related to the push should happen fast too. Methods like `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidLoad`, `loadView`, `viewDidAppear` and so on. `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` will put your lengthy task into the background, but unfortunately there is a huge queue of stuff you have to change to support the backgrounding. E.g. you can't update the UI from the background.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt weird, I thought so too, that "You can't update the UI from background", but it seems to *work*.. ?  It works.. but I'm confused..

Comment: @fluchtpunkt actually viewWill*/viewDid is happening before iphone present the view to the screen. That's why this is working?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what (I guess it depends mostly on the what) or why it is working. I just know from my experience that updating a UITableView or a UIWebview from the background leads to everything between nothing (update never happens), maybe later (update happens 5 seconds later), or a crash. --- I just read the doc again, and it says it is (sometimes) okay to create views from a background thread. So I guess everything before `addSubview:` could be done in the background. But I never tried this, and I probably never will.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt ok just fyi, I've tested more than 10 times, haven't crashed once.. i'll update here if it finally crashes.. cross fingers :(