# (iphone) start timer from background thread?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, nstimer

I create a timer with `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimerInterval:target:selector:...]` from a background thread
It seems the timer created from a background thread doesn't call the selector given as the argument.

Is there something special I need to run a timer from background thread?
Thank you

- EDIT

Here's the sequence

```
performSelectorInBackground: pushViewController
```

from the viewController's init sequence,

```
I alloc a timer with the above method.
```

and the timer selector won't get called.

Comment: Code example please, we're not psychic!

Comment: Thanks. But actual code please, not "paraphrased". Highly recommend reading this: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx  Quote: 'Don't give me code which is "something like" the real code but which clearly isn't the real code'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only do things to the UI - like pushing view controllers and changing UI items - from the main thread. If you don't, things break, as you can see.

See the Cocoa Fundamentals Guide section titled "Are the Cocoa Frameworks Thread Safe?": it says "All UIKit objects should be used on the main thread only."

**Original answer**

There's nothing special needed. The selector will get called on the thread you did the scheduleTimer call from.

Comment: @occulus thanks for reply, Yes I appended the ":", and I set a bp to see if it's getting called.

Comment: once I change the performselectorinbackground: pushViewController part to plain [navController pushViewController..] , timer works fine

Comment: My guess is that the thread that performed "pushViewController" is gone by the time view is loaded.. and timer was attached to the now-gone thread.(if there's a concept of attaching a timer to a thread)

Comment: [navController pushViewController] isn't doing anything with a timer, what do you mean?

Comment: @occulus the viewController being pushed creates a timer. (see my edit)

Comment: well, ok i put NSLog and no messages there

Comment: this is yet another problem.. I'm aware of "no updating UI from any other thread than main policy". Is doing pushViewController in background thread fine or is it against the policy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441856/iphone-sdk-leaking-memory-with-performselectorinbackground is this answer wrong then?

Comment: Yes, pushViewController should only be called from a background thread. That other answer you linked to is doing things badly. Will update my answer.